# Word table style from c#

Tags: c#-4.0, ms-word, silverlight-4.0, office-interop, com-interop

I have silverlight application that run out of browser. It opens some word template document and populate some fields. The problem is that in tpl document table is at top left corner. I want to change position of table to all 4 corners.. In word I can do that in table proporties, position but how could I do that form code?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to access the table programmatically via the office interop API
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.table.tables.aspx

Comment: yes I know that.. but how to change table position from interop API

Comment: I unfortunately do not know, best advice I can give is to take a browse through the table object members and see if one of the style properties will give you the effect you are looking for: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.table_members.aspx